# How does this mechanical heat click work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I own this vaporizer: [(product link)](https://www.dynavap.com/dynashop/vaporizers/omni/omnivap/xl-titanium)
[image: Dynavap vaporizer]
It has no electrical parts. To use it, you take off the cap at the left, put some "herbs" in it to smoke (vaporize), and put the cap back on. Then you heat the cap with a torch lighter until it says click. The click indicates that the cap (made of stainless steel) is at the right temperature. Then you can inhale from the right part and hot air with vaporized herbs will enter your body. It will click again when it has cooled down. [(video)](https://youtu.be/i86qSoFolVs)

How does this click work? Can I make this myself with a CNC machine?

The click system is at the end of the cap.

[image: Cap]

Comment: It's almost certainly a bimetallic strip which "snaps" into two different configs at the desired temperature boundary.   BTW,  "herbs"  as a name for solid vegetative mass will not vaporize. They'll either burn or won't; the amount of oils emitted prior to the smoke point is close to zero.  I wouldn't trust this device.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, Oh come on, you've got to trust this thing.  Look how shiny it is!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Specific compounds will release at different temperatures.  I've seen some crude ones back in university...  There definitely seem to be different compounds released at different temperatures.  They may all actually "burn"; but there seems to be a large market for "herbal vaporizers" designed to have control over burn temperatures.  Even if it's placebo; there's a huge market right now for regulating "herbal vaporization".  This just seems to be a passive device trying to ride the fad.

Comment: U.S. Patent Publication No. 2014/0186015 A1 describes the device in question. Not much details on how the click works from my read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flashers in your car that makes your blinkers blink used to work on the same principle. If you lightly bend a thin metal sheet, it will resist more to bending in the perpendicular direction. You can demonstrate it by holding a sheet of paper with one hand. It won't hang down if you push your thumb to curve the paper somewhat while holding it. But lightly push the other end of the paper down with your other hand, and eventually it will flip over and hang down.

Your vaporizer will probably work with that principle, but with a small metal sheet. And it is probably fitted in a location that compresses it, just like you pushed the other end of the paper.

That resistance to flipping over decreases as the temperature of the metal increases. So when heated, at some point, it will become weak enough to snap; creating the snapping sound.

Comment: So you don't think it's a bimetallic strip?

Comment: @Paul A bimetallic strip will bend when heated up, but gradually if it's a straight strip. But it could be a bimetallic strip, bend in the way i described. It's needlessly more expensive to produce though, so i'd expect just a metal strip. Formed to flip just like those hairclips young girls wear. They snap when enough force is applied on them, the clips, that is..